# DIVs should remain side by side within overflow:hidden parent

Tags: html, css, overflow, swipe

I'm trying to make multiple divs sit side-by-side in an "overflow: hidden" parent. Each child div must use 100% width of the parent component. This is to simulate "swiping" between each child div.

A jsfiddle to illustrate my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/f83qeoxc/3/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="i1" class="item">
      item 1
    </div>
    <div id="i2" class="item">
      item 2
    </div>
    <div id="i3" class="item">
      item 3
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.item{

  display: ineline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

StackOverflow already has plenty of material about this sort of issue. However, I couldn't find a solution that covers the following specifics:

- children may not have absolute positioning as the parent must resize based their content height.
- as each child has 100% width, only one has to appear at time, others are hidden by the parent' overflow-x property

Thanks for suggestions to solve this!

Comment: Why you don't want absolute position? I think you should use Jquery/Javascript.

Comment: @ketan hi, I must use a pure CSS solution. The parent must resize according the the active item's height (other will have -100% top/bottom margins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change css

```
 .wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;

}

  .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f83qeoxc/10/

Comment: Good job eliminating the float: left on child class. Thanks!